No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out" i can delete my account but not log out
Here is my error:

No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"

and this is all routes :
                                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                                       Controller#Action
                        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                          devise/sessions#new
                            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                          devise/sessions#create
                    destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                         devise/sessions#destroy
                       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                                                     devise/passwords#new
                      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                                    devise/passwords#edit
                           user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                                                         devise/passwords#update
                                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                                         devise/passwords#update
                                         POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                                         devise/passwords#create
                cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                                                           devise/registrations#cancel
                   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                          devise/registrations#new
                  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                                             devise/registrations#edit
                       user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                                                                  devise/registrations#update
                                         PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                                  devise/registrations#update
                                         DELETE /users(.:format)                                                                                  devise/registrations#destroy
                                         POST   /users(.:format)                                                                                  devise/registrations#create
                                 friends GET    /friends(.:format)                                                                                friends#index
                                         POST   /friends(.:format)                                                                                friends#create
                              new_friend GET    /friends/new(.:format)                                                                            friends#new
                             edit_friend GET    /friends/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                       friends#edit
                                  friend GET    /friends/:id(.:format)                                                                            friends#show
                                         PATCH  /friends/:id(.:format)                                                                            friends#update
                                         PUT    /friends/:id(.:format)                                                                            friends#update
                                         DELETE /friends/:id(.:format)                                                                            friends#destroy
                                    root GET    /                                                                                                 home#index
                              home_about GET    /home/about(.:format)                                                                             home#about
                      rails_health_check GET    /up(.:format)                                                                                     rails/health#show
                      pwa_service_worker GET    /service-worker(.:format)                                                                         rails/pwa#service_worker
                            pwa_manifest GET    /manifest(.:format)                                                                               rails/pwa#manifest
        turbo_recede_historical_location GET    /recede_historical_location(.:format)                                                             turbo/native/navigation#recede
        turbo_resume_historical_location GET    /resume_historical_location(.:format)                                                             turbo/native/navigation#resume
       turbo_refresh_historical_location GET    /refresh_historical_location(.:format)                                                            turbo/native/navigation#refresh
           rails_postmark_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/postmark/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/postmark/inbound_emails#create
              rails_relay_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/relay/inbound_emails(.:format)                                              action_mailbox/ingresses/relay/inbound_emails#create
           rails_sendgrid_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/sendgrid/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/sendgrid/inbound_emails#create
     rails_mandrill_inbound_health_check GET    /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#health_check
           rails_mandrill_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#create
            rails_mailgun_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mailgun/inbound_emails/mime(.:format)                                       action_mailbox/ingresses/mailgun/inbound_emails#create
          rails_conductor_inbound_emails GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                          rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#index
                                         POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                          rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#create
       new_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/new(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#new
           rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#show
new_rails_conductor_inbound_email_source GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources/new(.:format)                              rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources#new
   rails_conductor_inbound_email_sources POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources(.:format)                                  rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources#create
   rails_conductor_inbound_email_reroute POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/:inbound_email_id/reroute(.:format)                               rails/conductor/action_mailbox/reroutes#create
rails_conductor_inbound_email_incinerate POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/:inbound_email_id/incinerate(.:format)                            rails/conductor/action_mailbox/incinerates#create
                      rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs/redirect#show
                rails_service_blob_proxy GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/proxy/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                                  active_storage/blobs/proxy#show
                                         GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                                        active_storage/blobs/redirect#show
               rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/redirect/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations/redirect#show
         rails_blob_representation_proxy GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/proxy/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format)    active_storage/representations/proxy#show
                                         GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format)          active_storage/representations/redirect#show
                      rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                                       active_storage/disk#show
               update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                               active_storage/disk#update
                    rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                                    active_storage/direct_uploads#create


this is my header
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <%= link_to 'Friend App', root_path, class:"navbar-brand"%>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <%= link_to "about us", home_about_path, class:"nav-link" %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to "friends", friends_path, class:"nav-link" %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to "addfriend", new_friend_path, class:"nav-link" %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to "Sign Up", user_session_path, class:"nav-link" %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_registration_path , class:"nav-link" %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "nav-link" %>      
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to "Profile", edit_user_registration_path, class:"nav-link" %>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

my Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "rails", "~> 7.2.1"
gem "sprockets-rails"
gem "sqlite3", ">= 1.4"
gem "puma", ">= 5.0"
gem "importmap-rails"
gem "turbo-rails"
gem "stimulus-rails"
gem "jbuilder"
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ windows jruby ]
gem "bootsnap", require: false
gem 'devise', '~> 4.9', '>= 4.9.4'

group :development, :test do
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri windows ], require: "debug/prelude"

  gem "brakeman", require: false

  gem "rubocop-rails-omakase", require: false
end

group :development do
  gem "web-console"
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
end


and my application_controller
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Only allow modern browsers supporting webp images, web push, badges, import maps, CSS nesting, and CSS :has.
  allow_browser versions: :modern
end


i did  a new file creating a file registration .rb putting some code in it about sign out
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Logged out successfully.'
  end
end


and nothing changed  like delete method is not in it or something like that

Your logout link link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "nav-link" has method: :delete which is intended to mimic a HTTP DELETE verb request but your route is for destroy_user_session GET so either change your route to use the correct verb (recommended) or change the link to remove the method: :delete

my friend thx very much for helping me

@engineersmnky You may want to add this as an answer.

Devise by default should actually create a DELETE route not GET:
Prefix               Verb    URI Pattern      

destroy_user_session DELETE  /users/sign_out(.:format) ...

What I suspect that you have done is to set the sign_out_via option in config/initializers/devise.rb:
# The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
config.sign_out_via = :delete # <- you changed this to :get 

The reason the default is DELETE and not GET is request is that GET is supposed to be idempotent and GET requests are stored in the browsers history.
The reason people change it to GET is that they run into issues with using the Rails UJS or Turbo handler to get links to send a DELETE request and instead of actually fixing the problem they cop out as they have no JavaScript debugging skills. I don't recommend it.
What you should instead do is to just use button_to to create an accessible and robust log out option:
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= button_to "Log out", 
      destroy_user_session_path, 
      method: :delete, 
      class: "nav-link" 
  %>   
<% end %>   

This creates an actual form element so it will work even without any JS trickery. Screen readers and bots will also pick up that it's a form that does something special and not just a link.
If you absolutely have to use a link it's recommended that you use Turbo instead of the old Rails UJS method:
<%= link_to "Log out", 
    destroy_user_session_path, 
    data: { turbo_method: :delete }, 
    class: "nav-link" 
%>  

Rails UJS is not included by default in Rails 7 so I suspect that you have added it to your app or that clicking the link isn't what actually triggered the error.
Finally just get rid of your registration.rb. You don't need to override anything here. Just learn to actually use Devise and why it does things the way it does before you override anything.
